# SEVERE: The web application [/helloWorld] created a ThreadLocal with key of type

Tags: web-applications, tomcat7

Running a webapplication, on tomcat 7.0.29, while stopping the application the following error is thrown

```
    SEVERE: The web application [/helloWorld] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ClassFactory$1] (value 
[com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ClassFactory$1@1b7b32c]) and a value of type [java.util.WeakHashMap] (value [{class 
com.test.jaxws_asm.CreateSession=java.lang.ref.WeakReference@a06d25}]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped.
Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are these warnings in catalina.out?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9992526/what-are-these-warnings-in-catalina-out)

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7788280/memory-leak-when-redeploying-application-in-tomcat.

Comment: I have the same issue with glassFish 4...

Comment: Okay I got it resolved by manually deleting all the files related to problematic project on GlassFish server directory.